# Installing Virtual machine on a virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am implementing Oracle RAC using 11.2. For shared disc option and low cost, we are planning to use Virtual Machines. I have installed one virtual machine (PARENT).

Specifications:
- Oracle Linux 5.8 (64 bit)
- RAM 16GB
- HDD 90GB
- CPU 1

After installing VM, I tried to install another VM (CHILD) using Oracle Virtual Box.

Specification for CHILD vm
- Oracle Linux 5.8 (32 bit)  [ as Oracle VM doesnt give a 64 bit option while installing Child virtual machine]
- RAM 2GB 
- HDD 50GB
- CPU 1

Its giving error

> Starting udev:................................[Failed]

Questions:

1. What is the possible reason?
2. I want to use Oracle RAC using Linux 5.8. We have don't have other option than Linux. What is the procedure that I need to follow?
3. When I am installing Oracle VM Box on 64 bit machine, the option for 64 bit child machine is not available at the time of creating virtual machine. Why?

Comment: it will fail, the virtualized hardware will not be able to work because the drivers are not meant to work that way. I already see the question here

Comment: see for example http://serverfault.com/a/47028/131555

Comment: @Kiwy [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) does not appear to support nested virtualization, but both [KVM](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/virtual/kvm/nested-vmx.txt) and [XEN](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Nested_Virtualization_in_Xen) do support nested virtualization to and extent.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a feature request on the official Virtual Box site. You can follow the discussion [there](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) and see when it will (or if) it will be included.

I did read somewhere the [vmware, workstation 8](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws80/doc/releasenotes_workstation_80.html) includes this feature, but I have not verified or tested it.